# how to load OAuth certificate in dot net core

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, .net-core, dotnetopenauth, asp.net-core-1.0

we are implementing the new application in dot net core, in the part we need to use open id authentication with our SecureAuth server. I am unable to figure out how to load the certificate into OAuthOptions.

here is my code to use OAuth

```
var cert = new X509Certificate2(Path.Combine(env.ContentRootPath, "/Connect.cer"));


        var saOptions = new OAuthOptions
        {
            AuthenticationScheme = "ACR Connect",
            ClientId = Configuration["AppSettings:ConnectSettings:ClientID"],
            ClientSecret = Configuration["AppSettings:ConnectSettings:ClientSecret"],
            TokenEndpoint = Configuration["AppSettings:ConnectSettings:CallbackPath"],
            CallbackPath = Configuration["AppSettings:ConnectSettings:TokenEndpoint"],
            AuthorizationEndpoint = Configuration["AppSettings:ConnectSettings:TokenEndpoint"],
            UserInformationEndpoint = Configuration["AppSettings:ConnectSettings:UserInformationEndpoint"],
            ClaimsIssuer = Configuration["AppSettings:ConnectSettings:ClaimsIssuer"],



        };

        app.UseOAuthAuthentication(saOptions);
```

When we are implementing in MVC5 we are pretty much sure about syntax, but How to do in MVC6(Dot Net Core 1.0).

Comment: How do you use the `cert` variable?

Comment: Why do you need the cert if you are the consumer and not the auth server itself?

Comment: Related article: [OAuth Authorization with .Net Core](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1183421/Simple-OAuth-Authorization-Server-with-Identity-Se)